# django admin conditional relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I got such legacy DB:

```
class CarParamType(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class CarParam(models.Model):
      car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
      car_param_type = models.ForeignKey('CarParamType')
      value = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class DriveType(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Car(models.Model):
      vin = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And such admin site:

```
class CarParamAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
      model = CarParam


@admin.register(Car)
  class CarAdmin(CustomModelAdmin):
      inlines = [
          CarParamAdmin,
      ]
```

CarParamType is populated with names like weight, width, color and most important there is 'drive' record with related to DriveType id in CarParam value field.

It is possible to get something like:

```
if car_param_type.name == 'drive':
    form = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DriveType.objects.all())
```

..inside my TabularInline ?

Comment: To clarify, is your question regarding models, or model forms?

Comment: I just want to be able to select DriveType option in my admin.TabularInline. So when I got list of char fields related to params of my car, if param name is 'drive' instead of char input I want select dropdown